# Difference between AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store and AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm

I'm preparing the AWS Developer Associate certification and I don't understand the main difference between AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store and AWS Secrets Manager.

I read the presentation of each service and it feels like Secrets Manager is Parameter Store with the rotation functionality in extra.

In which use case do I use one over the other?

Someone to clarify?

Answer (score 3):

These services address distinct use cases and customer personas.

Parameter Store: Used by DevOps to store configuration data (e.g., IP address)

Secrets manager: Used by IT and Security administrators to manage the lifecycle (e.g., generate, rotate) of secrets (e.g., database credentials)